# Remove delimiter from text variable while reading

Tags: javascript, node.js

i received this file form the server and stored it automatically
Text file chall.txt :

```
"rnIgOUXql5SEgpYy6vul"
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
const fs = require('fs');
var challange = fs.readFileSync('chall.txt', 'utf8');
```

i want that variable to be stored like this **rnIgOUXql5SEgpYy6vul** not this **"rnIgOUXql5SEgpYy6vul"**
so i don't need every time open txt and remove delimiters

Comment: _"so i don't need every time open txt and remove delimiters"_: why not have the server just send the text without the quote marks? Otherwise just `const newStr = replaceAll('"', '')`, and then save the file with that content.

Comment: `replaceAll` was added to nodeJS in v15. What version are you using?

Comment: i were using v14 sorry i've update it to v18.2.0 Thank you it's work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the quotes.

```
const fs = require('fs');
let content = fs.readFileSync('chall.txt', 'utf-8');
content = content.replace('"', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you will do like this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
var challange = await fs.readFileSync('chall.txt', 'utf8');
let data = challenge.replace("\"", "");
```